# Close Full Screen Menu overlay when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, menu, overlay

I am learning JavaScript and I have spent a long time trying to find a fix for the above problem. I would like the full screen menu to close when a link is clicked. I can't for the life of me figure how to do it. Here is my JavaScript:

```
// Select DOM Items
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const menuNav = document.querySelector(".menu-nav");
const menuBranding = document.querySelector(".menu-branding");
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");

// Set Initial State Of Menu
let showMenu = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
  if (!showMenu) {
    menuBtn.classList.add("close");
    menu.classList.add("show");
    menuNav.classList.add("show");
    menuBranding.classList.add("show");
    navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.add("show"));

    // Set Menu State
    showMenu = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove("close");
    menu.classList.remove("show");
    menuNav.classList.remove("show");
    menuBranding.classList.remove("show");
    navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove("show"));

    // Set Menu State
    showMenu = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: There will be some more code for it. and what is class for overlay ?

Comment: Sorry it's not actually a class it's what I call the menu. That's all the Javascript I have for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't have to do all this stuff.
Just create another overlay div and add links inside it and make it's display as none.

```
.overlay{
position: fixed; 
display: none;
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 2;
background: #333;
}
```

And add event listener to the link tags and make overlay display none and that's it.

Comment: Thanks Ayush, this is what I am struggling with adding an event listener to the links when they are clicked. I'm on the right track.

Comment: Can you show me some snippet on your stylesheet. There might be some error in your css.

Comment: It won't let me post my CSS. I'm not an expert with Stack Overflow, how can I insert my css for the menu?

Comment: Just copy and paste and add 4 spaces before every line.

Comment: Or create a gist and share the link here.

Comment: It's not giving me the option to post anything other than text when I hit 'Add Comment'.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ayushgupta11/fb8a0023ab8e73a38e4cb71662207af5 . Here's my working gist. Please have a look at it. It might help.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ayushgupta11/705a1e83afaf5fc83f814d6c5c0cfcc7 . This is using plain JS. (No - Jquery)

Comment: Thank you Ayush, this is great I can incorporate the new functions in to my existing menu. I'll provide a link to the fully coded site then you can get a better understanding of how my menu works. Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: The only problem I'm having is when the menu disappears the burger icon (top right) which triggers the menu doesn't go back to its original state and simply rotates without showing the menu overlay on click.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, now when I click a nav link the menu and full screen overlay disappears and the menu/icon goes back to its original state. I added the following lines of code: menuNav.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu, false);
var init = function() {
  bindActions();
  menuNavClicked();
}; Actually I don't need to add false, anyway thanks for you help!

Comment: Glad to help you. Please mark this answer as correct. :)